# Accessing Google App Engine from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine

I want to request Google App Engine from window application, and I tried to use "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin" the following this articles: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=894.

But at now Google dont't support "ClientLogin".  I know how to authenticated my win application with Google Apis, but with Google App Engine I've no idea.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
- url: /do/something/
  script: something.py
  login: admin
```

Could anyone tell me how I can post data?
Thanks.

Comment: Actually I can request to Google App Engine but I can't authenticated user , then Google App Engine response "user not logged in".  Could someone know the way authenticated user Google App Engine when request from window application ?